# How to impose a constraint on contours frame by frame

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm implementing some piece of code in MATLAB to track left ventricle wall position in echocardiography images using a contour-based method. Unfortunately in some frames the contour evolves more than it is expected and in some regions the wall does not have good contrast.

Does anyone know a way to restrict contours from unexpected evolution from frame to frame saving both old frame's position and new one's shape?

Thank you all for helping.

Comment: We might be able to help if you post some code for us to look at please.

Comment: Thank you Soylent for helping but I do not have the complete code, in fact I'm cooperating with some other students. I have just images of contours(white) in a black background image(logical image), and my task is just to put a constraint on evolution. I have done some contour smoothing and so on, but the problem is sudden change in area of the contour. I should only do something knowing contour position.

Comment: @M.Jalali: Provide as much code as required to reproduce your problem.  Otherwise it is nearly impossible to help.

Answer (score 1):

Image segmentation is a hard problem. There is no general approach that works well in every situation. How are your contours being defined? Are you doing threshold-based segmentation, or using another approach? Have you tried transforming into a polar coordinate system in the centre of the LV? Have you tried quantifying some sort of 'least-squares' cost associated with moving the contour?

All I can suggest is look at how people solve similar problems. In my field (namely MRI), the best we have a) isn't really all that good, and b) is probably this open-source Matlab 'program' designed for cardiac segmentation called segment (see http://medviso.com/products/segment/features/cmr/). I suggest you look at how they do it, and see if you can adapt the method to work with the (much noisier, much harder to interpret) echo images.

Sorry I can't be more helpful!

Comment: Thank you Landak for useful hints.
I'm doing a piece of a group work and I have only the wall images (black background) traced by some method using thresholding. I'm asked to make the contour smooth and prevent from sudden evolution of wall position from one frame into another. I've already done the smoothing but real problem is the second part.
Any way, thank you for your help.

Comment: Does blob detection come into play here, or am I totally off track?  If so I would recommend researching some blob detection libraries, such as OpenCV.  Not sure if there is a way you can integrate that with Matlab however...